# DB2 insert content of textfile in long varchar column

Tags: sql, insert, db2, clob

I'm not very familiar with db2.. this task would be rather easy in Oracle but I don't know how to do it with db2.

I have the following table:

```
                            Data type                     Column
Column name                     schema    Data type name      Length     Scale Nulls
------------------------------- --------- ------------------- ---------- ----- ------
ID                                TEST    CHARACTER                   10     0 No    
BU                                TEST    CHARACTER                    5     0 No    
FILETYPE                          TEST    CHARACTER                    6     0 No    
FILENAME                          TEST    CHARACTER                   80     0 No    
PATH                              TEST    CHARACTER                  254     0 No    
TS                                TEST    TIMESTAMP                   10     0 Yes   
TSYS                              TEST    CHARACTER                   50     0 No    
STAT                              TEST    CHARACTER                    1     0 No    
REP                               TEST    LONG VARCHAR             32700     0 Yes
```

I want to create a new row and the column REP should contain the contents of a textfile.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either the IMPORT or LOAD command:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0008304.htmm

one catch though, I'm not sure that the LOB functionality is going to work with non-LOB columns... although LONG VARCHAR is very similar to CLOB, apart from the max. allowed data size.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. unfortunatly I was not able to solve my problem with IMPORT or LOAD